# dart shelf: Strange requests to my server: handlerPath "/" and url "43" must combine to equal requestedUri path "443"

Tags: dart, dart-shelf, shelf-router

I deployed dart `shelf_router` server to use as a service for my app.

Everything works fine in terms of service and code.

However, I see occasional (couple times per hour) strange request errors in journalctl logs, that I didn't make.

Why do these appear on their own?

I checked nginx logs and nothing seem to be coming from the outside.

As you can see below dart `shelf_router` also tell about different path, like "443", "80".

```
Jul 24 07:38:39 localhost dart[2844193]: Error parsing request.
Jul 24 07:38:39 localhost dart[2844193]: Invalid argument (requestedUri): handlerPath "/" and url "0" must combine to equal requestedUri path "80".: Instance of '_SimpleUri'
Jul 24 07:38:39 localhost dart[2844193]: dart:isolate  _RawReceivePort._handleMessage
```

```
Jul 24 08:48:25 localhost dart[2860151]: Error parsing request.
Jul 24 08:48:25 localhost dart[2860151]: Invalid argument (requestedUri): handlerPath "/" and url "43" must combine to equal requestedUri path "443".: Instance of '_SimpleUri'
Jul 24 08:48:25 localhost dart[2860151]: dart:isolate  _RawReceivePort._handleMessage
```

I'd be very grateful for any guesses and clues as I'm new to dart shelf!